# How to keep "back to app" button in opened application until unless use clicks that button

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

If in case user close application or click on the home button also

---Thanks in advance.

Comment: you do not have access to those parts of the software, so: you cannot

Answer (score 0):

Apple **restricts** app developers to access certain parts of the software, in order to protect the security of the users. That being said, accessing the ***back to app*** button cannot be changed or modified inside your app, because it is not a piece of software which belongs to your app.

---

From what you have described, it seems that you want your app to just take control of your user, putting that button there whenever the user exists your app. It is not the case.